# Possible typo in Schwartz's QFT, p. 629

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, quantum-anomalies, chirality

I'm trying to see whether this is my own misunderstanding or a typo in Schwartz's QFT book. Any help or feedback appreciated.

Schwartz talks about Chiral anomalies from the integral measure. The transformation of fields is:

$$
\psi \to e^{i \beta(x) \gamma_5} \psi
$$

Measure transforms as:

$$
\int {\cal{D}}\psi {\cal{D}} \overline{\psi} \to
  \int \frac{1}{|{\cal{J}}|^2} {\cal{D}}\psi {\cal{D}} \overline{\psi}
$$

Using ${\cal{J}} = \det \Delta = \exp tr \ln \Delta$, we get in (30.60):

$$
{\cal{J}} = \exp\left(i \int d^4x \, \beta(x) Tr\left[\gamma_5\right] \right)
$$

Now Schwartz says that this appears to vanish, and therefore the measure becomes singular.

Isn't the only vanishing thing in that formula $Tr\left[\gamma_5 \right]$? If this is the case - shouldn't $\cal{J}$ be equal to 1?

---

Weinberg's treatment of this is rather different and <s>possibly has an error too (although, I'm not sure about this either)</s>:

$$
\frac{1}{|{\cal{J}}|^2} = \exp \left\{ i \int d^4x \, \alpha(x) {\cal{A}}(x) \right\}
$$

$$
{\cal{A}}(x) = -2 Tr \left\{ \gamma_5 \right\} \delta^4(x - x)
$$

In my understanding $\delta^4(x - x)$ shouldn't be really there. For example, given ${\cal{U}} = \alpha(x)$ the trace must be:

$$
Tr \left\{ {\cal{U}} \right\} = \int d^4x \, \alpha(x)
$$

<s>Is there an error too?</s>

**Update** After giving it a bit of thought, I see that Weinberg is right (as usual). There must be infinity coming from the delta-function in this kind of trace, e.g. transformation like:

$$
\psi \to 2 \psi
$$

Should have infinite Jacobian since we multiply field at every point of spacetime.

Comment: The update (v5) reads more like an answer.

Comment: Yeah, it is answered indeed. Is there any way to mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(It is a bit weird to answer my own question, but...)*

I'm confident that this is an error in a book. The delta function must be in the exponential, and $\cal{J}$ is not going to vanish in any case. There are more than this in this chapter, and everything was reported to the author.

Will update this answer once I'll get a response from the author.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or understood why the measure should become singular?

Comment: I can't recall the details, but this is resolved in the latest edition of the book.